# How to get Springpython container to pick up changes to code

Tags: python, ioc-container

I am using springpython as follows:

```
from springpython.context import ApplicationContext
from springpython.config import XMLConfig   
appContext=ApplicationContext(XMLConfig("service.xml"))
service = appContext.get_object("service")
```

If I run this from the interpreter, how do I get the container to reload updates to the service.py file? Since I have not explicitly started the container in the code, I am not sure how to restart. 
Do I need to stop & start the python session?
How is it recommended that one makes changes during development?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Python doesn't have any built in file monitoring capabilities, so it can't by itself detect changes. You need to write something that watches service.xml, perhaps hashes it's content or watches the mtime, and when it changes, and re-build the appContext.

Comment: What are the steps to rebuild appContext? During a session, can I just set it to null and rerun these commands. appContext=ApplicationContext(XMLConfig("service.xml"))
service = appContext.get_object("service")